# Gradle Spoon: Plugin with id 'spoon' not found

Tags: android-testing, android-espresso, android-instrumentation, spoon-gradle-plugin

Trying to use spoon framework with Android Studio gradle project but getting an error when trying to add spoon plugin :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

    dependencies {
           classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
           classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'spoon'
        repositories {
                  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
      androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.3.2'
}
```

Error:(13, 0) Plugin with id 'spoon' not found

and :

```
Error:Could not find com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.4.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Apps/Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/stanfy/spoon/spoon-gradle-   plugin/1.0.4/spoon-gradle-plugin-1.0.4.pom
file:/C:/Apps/Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/stanfy/spoon/spoon-gradle-plugin/1.0.4/spoon-gradle-plugin-1.0.4.jar
https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/stanfy/spoon/spoon-gradle-plugin/1.0.4/spoon-gradle-plugin-1.0.4.pom
https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/stanfy/spoon/spoon-gradle-plugin/1.0.4/spoon-gradle-plugin-1.0.4.jar
```

gradle command line complaints about this link:

https://maven.fabric.io/public/com/stanfy/spoon/spoon-gradle-plugin/1.0.4/spoon-gradle-plugin-1.0.4.jar

Answer (score 2):

Did you noticed that your project has two build.gradle files? I'm pretty sure you added to one file and that's the problem you're facing

In first `build.gradle` (app) you should have dependencies like these:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'spoon'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.databindingexample"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'

    androidTestCompile 'com.squareup.spoon:spoon-client:1.3.2'

}
```

In the second `build.gradle` file (yourApplicationName), you should have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha1'
        classpath 'com.stanfy.spoon:spoon-gradle-plugin:1.0.4'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Hope this would  help you

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

```
dependencies {
      classpath 'de.felixschulze.gradle:gradle-spoon-plugin:2.7.3' 
}    

apply plugin: 'de.felixschulze.gradle.spoon'
```